# Compare two arrays of objects, where objects in each array have different properties

Tags: javascript

I have two result sets like this:

```
const resultSet1 =
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "version": "3",
        "website": "https://xx/version/3",
        "name": Ana,
        "lastName": Ana,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "version": "3",
        "website": "https://xx/version/3",
        "name": Ana,
        "lastName": Ana,
        
    }
]


const resultSet2 =
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "version": "2",
        "birthday": "24.08.1984",
        "place": "Europe",  

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "version": "2",
        "birthday": "24.08.1984",
        "place": "Europe",  
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "version": "1",
        "birthday": "24.08.1984",
        "place": "Europe",  
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "version": "3",
        "birthday": "24.08.1984",
        "place": "Europe",  
    }
]
```

I want to compare these two result sets, based on `id` & `version`. In my `const comparisonSet`, I want to have elements from the first result set, whose both `id` & `version` are **not** present in the second result set.

```
const comparisonSet = 

    [
    {
            "id": "1",
            "version": "3",
            "website": "https://xx/version/3",
            "name": Ana,
            "lastName": Ana,
        }
    ]
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the desired result.

**Overall complexity - O(n * 2)**

```
resultSet1.filter(({ id, version }) =>!resultSet2.find((o) => o.id === id && o.version === version));
```

```js
const resultSet1 = [{
    id: "1",
    version: "3",
    website: "https://xx/version/3",
    name: "Ana",
    lastName: "Ana",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "3",
    website: "https://xx/version/3",
    name: "Ana",
    lastName: "Ana",
  },
];

const resultSet2 = [{
    id: "1",
    version: "2",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "2",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    version: "1",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "3",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
];

const result = resultSet1.filter(
  ({
    id,
    version
  }) =>
  !resultSet2.find((o) => o.id === id && o.version === version)
);

console.log(result);
```

Though it is not so optimized, so you can also create a dictionary and loop up result in O(1) -

**Overall complexity O(n)**

```
const dict = resultSet2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, version } = curr;
  acc[`${id}|${version}`] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = resultSet1.filter(({ id, version }) => !dict[`${id}|${version}`]);
```

```js
const resultSet1 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    version: "3",
    website: "https://xx/version/3",
    name: "Ana",
    lastName: "Ana",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "3",
    website: "https://xx/version/3",
    name: "Ana",
    lastName: "Ana",
  },
];

const resultSet2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    version: "2",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "2",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    version: "1",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    version: "3",
    birthday: "24.08.1984",
    place: "Europe",
  },
];

const dict = resultSet2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, version } = curr;
  acc[`${id}|${version}`] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = resultSet1.filter(({ id, version }) => !dict[`${id}|${version}`]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yeah this is cleaner than mine

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate through one array while [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the other.

```js
resultSet1.forEach(res1 => {
  const filtered = resultSet2.filter(res2 => res2.id === res1.id && res2.version === res1.version);
  //if filtered.length === 0 you can do what you want with res1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Ana = 'Ana';
const resultSet1 = [
  { id: '1', version: '3', website: 'https://xx/version/3', name: Ana, lastName: Ana, },
  { id: '2', version: '3', website: 'https://xx/version/3', name: Ana, lastName: Ana, },
];

const resultSet2 = [
  { id: '1', version: '2', birthday: '24.08.1984', place: 'Europe', },
  { id: '2', version: '2', birthday: '24.08.1984', place: 'Europe', },
  { id: '1', version: '1', birthday: '24.08.1984', place: 'Europe', },
  { id: '2', version: '3', birthday: '24.08.1984', place: 'Europe', },
];

const idAndVersionNotInSecondResultSet = ({ id, version }) =>
  resultSet2.every(({ id: i, version: v }) => i !== id || version !== v);

const comparisonSet = resultSet1.filter(idAndVersionNotInSecondResultSet);

console.log(comparisonSet);
```